# Passing in model to partial view using abstract class

Tags: c#, razor, model, abstract, superclass

My abstract superclass TogglePanelViewModel which has 5 overridable properties
4 being virtual as it has default values set and one abstract. I want to use this abstract
viewmodel in a partial view which is then rendered by the subclasses that inherit TogglePanelViewModel.

My questions are:-

- Is this the right approach or can it be implemented in another way?
- As I cannot create an instance of TogglePanelViewModel, how do I pass in the viewmodel (subclass) into the partial?

Here is the code

The abstract viewmodel:

```
public abstract class TogglePanelViewModel
{
    public abstract string LSName { get; }
    public virtual string LabelText { get; set; } = "Hide welcome text|Show welcome text";
    public virtual string StyleClass { get; set; } = "";
    public virtual string StylePullRight { get; set; } = "pull-right";
    public virtual bool RenderLabelAfterToggle { get; set; } = false;
}
```

Shared partial view using abstract view model:

```
@model App.Website.Areas.Default.ViewModels.TogglePanelViewModel

<div class="@Model.StyleClass toggle-filter @Model.StylePullRight" id="ls" name="@Model.LSName">
    @if (Model.RenderLabelAfterToggle == false)
    {
        <div class="toggle-label">
            <span>@Model.LabelText</span>
        </div>
    }
    <div class="common-slide-checkbox @Model.StylePullRight">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="toggle-filter-visible">
        <label for="toggle-filter-visible" id="toggle-pos"></label>
        <div id="toggle-bg"></div>
    </div>
    @if (Model.RenderLabelAfterToggle == true)
    {
        <div class="toggle-label">
            <span>@Model.LabelText</span>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Ex: 1 of a base class which inherits TogglePanelViewModel

Which will give error

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'App.Website.Areas.Create.Models.IdeationViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'App.Website.Areas.Default.ViewModels.TogglePanelViewModel'.
```

Also cannot create instance new TogglePanelViewModel {  }

View:

```
@using App.Website.Areas.Default.ViewModels
@model App.Website.Areas.Create.Models.IdeationViewModel

<div>
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/TogglePanel.cshtml", Model.ToggleIdeationFilter)
</div>
```

Viewodel:

```
public class IdeationViewModel
{
    ...
    public ToggleIdeationFilterVM ToggleIdeationFilter { get; set; }
}

public class ToggleIdeationFilterVM : TogglePanelViewModel
{
    public override string LSName => null;
    public override string LabelText => "Hide filter|Show filter";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `IdeationViewModel` and `TogglePanelViewModel` are two different classes. You need to inherit `TogglePanelViewModel` from `IdeationViewModel` to achieve what you are looking for right now

Comment: I can't do this because I want to set the properties in ToggleIdeationFilterVM. I probably can inherit ToggleIdeationFilterVM from IdeationViewModel but I would feel as this could be written a better way

Comment: Then you should pass instance of `ToggleIdeationFilterVM` as model to the view. Not the instance of `TogglePanelViewModel`

Comment: that's it thanks. no idea why i didn't think of this..

Answer (score 0):

Answer: pass instance of ToggleIdeationFilterVM as a model to the partial view:-

```
@Html.Partial("~/Areas/Default/Views/Shared/TogglePanel.cshtml", new ToggleIdeationFilterVM())
```